# TensorFlow binary classification task bad accuracy, but SciKit-Learn GBM works well

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, tensorflow

I used the following tensorflow implementation for a binary classification task and got really bad accuracy. However when I trained the same dataset with a `sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier` without any tuning and the result was pretty good. When I took a deep look at the out-of-sample predictions of the neural network made, I realized most of the predictions were the positive class.

```
         precision    recall  f1-score   support

      0       0.01      1.00      0.02         8
      1       1.00      0.37      0.55      1630

avg / total       1.00      0.38      0.54      1638
```

The implementation of 2 layer fully connected network:

```
import math
batch_size = 200
feature_size = len(train_features.columns)

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():

  # Input data. For the training data, we use a placeholder that will be fed
  # at run time with a training minibatch.
  tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, feature_size))
  tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels))
  tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
  tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)

  # Variables.
  weights1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([feature_size, 512]))
  biases1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([512]))

  weights2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([512, 512], stddev=0.005))
  biases2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([512]))

  weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([512, num_labels], stddev=0.005))
  biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_labels]))

  hidden_layer1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_train_dataset, weights1) + biases1)
  hidden_layer2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(hidden_layer1, weights2) + biases2)
  logits = tf.matmul(hidden_layer2, weights) + biases

  loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, tf_train_labels))

  # Optimizer.
  optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0005).minimize(loss)

  # Predictions for the training, validation, and test data.
  train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

  valid_hidden_layer1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_valid_dataset, weights1) + biases1)
  valid_hidden_layer2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(valid_hidden_layer1, weights2) + biases2)
  valid_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(valid_hidden_layer2, weights) + biases)

  test_hidden_layer1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_test_dataset, weights1) + biases1)
  test_hidden_layer2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(test_hidden_layer1, weights2) + biases2)
  test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(test_hidden_layer2, weights) + biases)
```

Any suggestion on how to debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sklearn GradientBoostingClassifier is a different algorithm than a neural network. It does something based on regression trees, which require less fine tuning in order to give good performance than neural networks. This is the trade-off when using neural networks; if you want performance better than alternative algorithms like random forests and SVM, you need to tune the hyper parameters.

As far as that goes, the first thing you should do is initialize the bias on your relu units to nonzero. This helps prevent them from entering a regime where they 'die' and end up giving 0 output and 0 gradient forever. You should also try different learning rates; a learning rate too high will cause the algorithm to not learn properly, and too low will waste resources.

You should also experiment with the number of neurons and layers. I see you have 512 neurons in each hidden layer, and this might be too much unless your problem is that high of dimension and you have enough data. What is your training and test/cross-validation error like? You should keep track of these while you train. If you're getting low training error but high validation error, then you should cut down on the number of neurons because you are overfitting. You could also try having just one hidden layer and see if that helps.